# Netsuite: Sort categories by what's in stock?

Tags: netsuite

In Netsuite, on a category page, is there a way to sort by what's in stock? So those things in stock show up at the top of a category?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. There are 3 ways I know of to achieve this.

- use a saved search based category instead of a static category. Make sure the layout uses Sort by Sequence. Remember NS caches these for 6 hours so updates are not immediate.
- can run a scheduled script that targets certain categories; have the script remove out-of-stock items from the category and then add them back in. This has the effect of moving them to the end of the category list
- similar but run the script on stock affecting transactions (SO commitments; Item Receipts; each out-of-stock item would remove itself and re-add itself to all categories. I would actually post the affected item ids to a queue (custom record) and work through that every 15 minutes.

in either of the scheduled script cases you'd probably want to take advantage of `{disabletriggers:true,enablesourcing:false}` to minimize unnecessary user events firing.

```
var itemRec = nlapiLoadRecord(ki.getRecordType(), ki.getId());
itemRec.insertLineItem('sitecategory', 1); // at the start
itemRec.setLineItemValue('sitecategory', 'category', 1, targetCat);
nlapiSubmitRecord(itemRec,{disabletriggers:true,enablesourcing:false});
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "use a saved search based category instead of a static category". When I go in and edit a category, I don't see a way to configure it that way. You just add items to it.

Comment: It's a different type of category. Lists -> Website -> Publish Saved Search.

Answer (score 0):

This is what we use to sort items by quantity and then by item name. You'd have to tweak the tags, ids, etc. to match your own info where needed, but this is basically it.

```
function ReadXMLData(selectLayout) {
    var itemName = document.getElementsByTagName('itemdisplayname');
    var storeDesc = document.getElementsByTagName('storediscription');
    var desc = document.getElementsByTagName('discription');
    var itemQuantity = document.getElementsByTagName('itemquantity');
    var itemPrice = document.getElementsByTagName('itemprice');
    var itemImgUrl = document.getElementsByTagName('itemimgurl');
    var itemUrl = document.getElementsByTagName('itemurl');
    var displayName2 = document.getElementsByTagName('itemdisplayname2');
    var itemSKU = document.getElementsByTagName('itemid');
    var internalId = document.getElementsByTagName('iteminternalid');
    var itemList = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < itemName.length; i++) {
        itemList.push({
            Name: itemName[i].innerHTML,
            Description: storeDesc[i].innerHTML,
            Desc: desc[i].innerHTML,
            Quantity: parseInt(itemQuantity[i].innerHTML),
            Price: itemPrice[i].innerHTML,
            ImageURL: itemImgUrl[i].innerHTML,
            StoreURL: itemUrl[i].innerHTML,
            DisplayName2: displayName2[i].innerHTML,
            InternalId: internalId[i].innerHTML,
            ItemSKU: itemSKU[i].innerHTML
        });
    }
    //Sort the array by quantity descending order and then by name ascending order
    var sortedList = Enumerable.From(itemList)
        .OrderByDescending(function(x) {
            return x.Quantity
        })
        .ThenBy(function(x) {
            return x.Name
        })
        .ToArray();
    if (document.getElementById('itemDisplayArea')) {
        document.getElementById('itemDisplayArea')
            .innerHTML = '<br/>' + GetLayoutHTML(selectLayout, sortedList);
    }
    if (selectLayout == "imgList") {
        DisplayDescription(sortedList);
    } else {
        DisplayStarGrid(sortedList);
    }
}
```